# Question on a Crazy Integral With Feynman’s Trick

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Concerning the integral,

$$\int_0^\pi \ln(e^3 + e^2 + e + 1 - 2\pi\cos(x))dx$$,

I managed to solve by defining and then differentiating wrt a:

$$I(a) := \int_0^\pi \ln(a - 2\pi\cos(x))dx$$

But I was curious if there was any other way to do this. Its  closed form is 
$$\pi\ln\Bigl(\sqrt{\bigl(\frac{1-e^4}{1-e}\bigr)^2 - 4\pi^2} + \bigl(\frac{1-e^4}{1-e}\bigr) \Bigr) - \pi\ln(2)$$.

Comment: Please don't put generic words like "question" in the title. All posts on this site are (or should be) questions.

Comment: So what would you put then?

Comment: Well, I personally would write something like "Alternative to evaluating integral with Feynman's trick", but the point wasn't to tell you what to write. Words like "crazy", "challenging", "difficult" are very subjective; I wouldn't consider this a "crazy integral"; but if you feel that that describes the integral well, "Crazy integral without Feynman's trick" would do. The point was just that it's an utter waste of space on the main page, in search results etc. to put "question" in front of every question on the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$I=\int_0^\pi \log\left(e^3 + e^2 + e + 1 - 2\pi\cos(x)\right)\,dx$$ Let $a=e^3 + e^2 + e + 1$ and $b=-2\pi$
$$I(b)=\int_0^\pi \log\left(a+b\cos(x)\right)\,dx$$
$$I'(b)=\int_0^\pi \frac{\cos (x)}{a+b \cos (x)}\,dx=\pi\frac{\frac{  a}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}+1 }{b}$$
$$I(b)=\pi \int \frac{\frac{  a}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}+1 }{b}\,db=\pi\left(2 \log (b)-\log \left(\sqrt{a^2-b^2}+a\right)\right)+C$$ Ajust the conditions ans replace $a$ and $b$ by their values.

There is another way to do it (direct integration) but the problem is that the antiderivative involves a few polylogarithm functions and it is quite messy (have a look [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate++log%28a%2Bb+cos%28x%29%29+for+x)).

Comment: Interesting. I didn’t think to paramaterize it that way. Thanks!

Comment: This is famous intimidation shield. Replace complicated stuff by a single symbol and simplify the problem considerably +1.